# In BIRT report viewer, how to cancel report execution in initialization event script?

Tags: birt

In the initialization event of a report in the BIRT report viewer, I want to cancel (terminate) the continued execution of the report, based on some validation taking place there.

pseudoCode: `reportContext(stop);`

After an enormous amount of research, I find only a single reference to the idea: "There is a way to cancel the task but this will cause a very generic exception."  But I can find nothing about how to cancel the running of a BIRT report from JavaScript code in a BIRT event handler, specifically the initialization event. The generic exception, I can deal with.
Anybody resolved this problem?

Comment: Thanks. In this Tomcat application, I wanted to terminate the report process based on logged-in status, before the user even got as far as having the param form show. I could have used a hidden param, but I wanted to stop the process before the report form appeared at all. I have worked out a way to terminate the process in datasource.beforeOpen, by setting the d/b username and password to invalid values. But the user still sees the form (labels in the header, etc.). With no data, of course. The user gets an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add JavaScript code to the `validate` event handler of a Report Parameter.
The report will only run if this script evaluates `true`. If `false` you'll get the "generic exception" you mentioned...

Comment: Thanks. In this Tomcat application, I wanted to terminate the report process based on logged-in status, before the user even got as far as having the param form show. I could have used a hidden param, but I wanted to stop the process before the report form appeared at all. I have worked out a way to terminate the process in datasource.beforeOpen, by setting the d/b username and password to invalid values. But the user still sees the form (labels in the header, etc.). With no data, of course. The user gets an error.